# Ozeki.Common.VoIPException : 'Error Code: 10013. Could not allocate media channel Audio. All ports are busy.'

Tags: c#, ozeki

In the sample project of Ozeki, I am getting below exception while accepting the answer.

```
Ozeki.Common.VoIPException: 'Error Code: 10013. Could not allocate media channel Audio. All ports are busy.'
```

How can I resolve it.